# Extract html payload from packet header without capfile

Tags: python, tcp, scapy

I try to capture packets by scapy and python but cant bring it to work to extract the tcp body from the tcp header. I really followed a lot of tutorials over night but still havent found my solution. (sorry, cant post all the links) also i would like to decompress content to see and maybe use regex on html code inside. i know there are a lot of tools but i want to have the opportunity do sniff by myself. thats my capture code, maybe someone could bring it to work. thank you.

```
packetCount = 0

def customAction(packet):
    global packetCount
    packetCount += 1
    #payload = packet[0][1].payload
    #payload = packet.getlayer(IP).payload
    payload=IP()/TCP()/Raw().load

    return "#%s: %s => %s => %s" % (packetCount, packet[0][1].src, packet[0][1].dst, payload)
```

Comment: How is `packet` defined?

Comment: its an ip packet of course, what else should it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to extract the *TCP* payload from an *IP* packet you may perform `packet[TCP].payload` or `packet[RAW]`.

Comment: ok i also tried that. maybe its compressed content so i get garbage when print to screen?

Comment: Edit the script to print the hex representation of the payload and compare its output to that of a _tcpdump_ \ _wireshark_ sniff.